# Identifying an element from a group, span[i] is the differentiating factor

Tags: selenium, xpath

[I have added the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQnMA.png) I have a group of elements that have the exact same xpath except the span tag.I want to identify the individual input fields, but unable to.

I have tried using contains, with class but unable to attach span to the xpath

Here is what the HTML looks like:

/html/body/div[@id='app']/div/div[@class='LayoutModify_LayoutModify_1Akxb']/main[@class='LayoutModify_main_5aBy3']/section[@class='sub-detail inner ProductDetail_productdetail_bJWN2']/div[@class='ProductDetail_productsphere_kgNGm']/div[@class='ProductDetail_threecol_2zA1n **ProductDetail_productsphereleft_2pLZT**']/**span[4]**/div[@class='el-input el-input--medium ProductDetail_productsphereinput_3eVZg']/input[@class='el-input__inner']

/html/body/div[@id='app']/div/div[@class='LayoutModify_LayoutModify_1Akxb']/main[@class='LayoutModify_main_5aBy3']/section[@class='sub-detail inner ProductDetail_productdetail_bJWN2']/div[@class='ProductDetail_productsphere_kgNGm']/div[@class='ProductDetail_threecol_2zA1n **ProductDetail_productsphereright_3BrqC**']/**span[4]**/div[@class='el-input el-input--medium ProductDetail_productsphereinput_3eVZg']/input[@class='el-input__inner']

Notice the span[4] and span[15] are the only differences

Comment: Can you post the html code that these two expressions point to?

Comment: Could You please post HTML snippet here please?

Answer (score 0):

Quick question: 
do either of these locators:

**locator A**

```
//span[4]/div/input[@class='el-input__inner']
```

**locator B**

```
//span[15]/div/input[@class='el-input__inner']
```

find any input on Your page?

If not - could You please post here the whole HTML page code here please?

Comment: I was able to identify, two elements.So they have right columns and left columns, I have updated the html pasted above and highlighted the differences. I used the below expression xpath helper return 1 result found, but the field is not highlighted.

//*[contains(@class, 'productsphereleft')] and //span[4]/div/input[@class='el-input__inner']

Comment: I will try to post the HTML, when I download, the offline HTML redirects to the login screen, a possible security measure, I will try to figure it out and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time Eugene, I was able to use it and identify the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath that worked: 
//div[contains(@class,'ProductDetail_productsphereright')]/span[4]/div/input